# Spring Boot Controller Test: mocking service requiring downstream objects causing ApplicationContext to not load

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, jpa, entitymanager

I am attempting to run a controller-level Spring Boot unit test with a Mock for my service-layer dependency.  However, this Mock is requiring  a downstream repository dependency which uses an `EntityManager` object, which is causing my test to fail on loading the `ApplicationContext`.

My test does not involve the repository dependency or `EntityManager`, it is using the Mocked service object to return a canned response. Why is Spring complaining about the repo/`EntityManager` if I only want to mock the service-layer object?

Controller unit test code:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest
@AutoConfigureWebClient
public class MobileWearControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    UserDeviceService userDeviceService;

    //.....
}
```

UserDeviceService code:

```
@Service
public class UserDeviceService {

    private UserDeviceRepository userDeviceRepository;

    public UserDeviceService(UserDeviceRepository userDeviceRepository) {
        this.userDeviceRepository = userDeviceRepository;
    }

    //....
}
```

UserDeviceRepository code:

```
@Repository
public class UserDeviceRepositoryImpl implements UserDeviceRepositoryCustom {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    //....
}
```

Expecting the test to run.

Actual result is getting the following stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDeviceRepositoryImpl': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available
...
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the `@AutoConfigureWebClient`? Out of interest.

Comment: @EngineerDollery same result, still getting the "No qualify bean of Type EntityManagerFactory" exception:
aused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available
 at 
...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My issue was the annotations I was using for my test.

Using @AutoConfigureWebClient tries to standup the entire Spring Context; since I am unit testing my controller I want to test only the web layer and mock the downstream dependencies (ie UserDeviceService).  So, I should be using @SpringBootTest and @AutoConfigureMockMvc instead, which will set up my Spring context only for the controller layer.

Using this approach I'm able to get UserDeviceService to mock successfully and thus allowing my test to compile and run:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class MobileWearControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    UserDeviceService userDeviceService;

    //...
}
```

Comment: Glad you got there in the end

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to specify what controllers you are going to test

`@WebMvcTest(YourController.class)`

Additionally, With JUnit5, you don't need to configure any extensions, as `@WebMvcTest` contains `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`. You are apparently on JUnit4, but this shouldn't do any harm.

Check for example https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/

Comment: I included my controller class in the @WebMvcTest annotation but still getting the same result:

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1090)
 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:580)
 at 
...

Comment: Yes, Me too getting the same issue.. 

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customerRepo': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available`

Comment: @sen WebMvcTest applies only configuration relevant to MVC test. In particular, `@Repository` beans missing from the context. For repositories, adding a `@MockBean` Repository in your test is a common approach. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcTest.html